# Failed to update custom domain properties

Tags: azure, cdn

When switching on https on a custom domain on an Azure CDN I get the following error:

**Failed to update custom domain properties**

CertificateType value provided is not supported for this profile for enabling https.

[image]

[image]

The screen looks different than in the tutorial [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cdn/cdn-custom-ssl?tabs=option-1-default-enable-https-with-a-cdn-managed-certificate).

There is no option to select "Certificate Management Type"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It appears to be a glitch in the azure portal's UI. The workaround that worked for me is to [enable HTTPS for the custom domain via the CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/cdn/custom-domain?view=azure-cli-latest#az_cdn_custom_domain_enable_https).

e.g.
`az cdn custom-domain enable-https --endpoint-name ENDPOINT_NAME --name CUSTOM_DOMAIN_NAME -g RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME --profile-name PROFILE_NAME`

note, CUSTOM_DOMAIN_NAME is the name of the custom domain entity in azure which is NOT equal to the actual domain name displayed in Azure portal. You can find the name you need by observing the output of the following command:
`az cdn custom-domain list --endpoint-name ENDPOINT_NAME -g RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME --profile-name PROFILE_NAME`

Once this is done, the UI on the custom domain properties page looks exactly as on the screenshot from the tutorial :)

Comment: his worked for me if anyone is encountering the same issue.